# Property 'closeModal' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

estoy haciendo una ventana modal con ReactJS y TypeScript pero estoy presentando un problema en el parámetro de mi componente y no se porque, alguno me podría ayudar?

```
 const ModalExit: React.FC = ({ closeModal }) => {
  return (
    <div className="p-6 max-w-sm mx-auto bg-white rounded-xl shadow-lg flex items-center space-x-4">
      <div>
        <p className="text-base text-font-color font-raleway mb-2">
          Do you want to leave the website?
        </p>
        <p className="text-xs text-font-color font-raleway">
          If you leave this website the changes will not saved.
        </p>
        <div className="w-full grid grid-cols-2 mt-4 place-items-start">
          <button className="cursor-pointer rounded-lg bg-primary-color text-white font-semibold px-8 h-10">
            Leave
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={() => closeModal(false)}
            className="cursor-pointer bg-transparent rounded-lg text-primary-color font-semibold px-8 h-10 border border-primary-color"
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

TS2339: Property 'closeModal' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.

Comment: Muestra la definición de `closeModal` en TS.

Answer (score 1):

#### FC type y props como Generic typed argument

Cuando se usa `FC (FunctionComponent)` type, hay que pasar las descripciones de `props` mediante un **generic typed argument**, ya que FC internamente, solo esta configurado para reconocer la prop `children`, en este caso como no se esta pasando un generic typed argument, `TypeScript` se queja:

> TS2339: Property 'closeModal' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.

Este `generic typed argument` será donde esta la descripción de `closeModal`, suponiendo que fuera una `interface`:

```
interface Props {
     closeModal : boolean;
}
//generic typed var <Props>
const ModalExit : FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ closeModal }) => {
    //codigo…
}
```

Si no se va a usar la prop `children`, entonces se podría configurar el componente sin FC, y pasar la interface como propiedad en la definición del componente:

```
const ModalExit = ({ closeModal } : Props) => {
    //codigo…
}
```

De hecho, [no se recomienda el uso de React.FC](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/function_components/)

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.